# Resharper equivalent of CodeRush's "Tab" shortcut (go to next/prev usage)

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, coderush

I'm trying to switch to Resharper from CodeRush and really struggling with this one.

In CodeRush when you are over a variable/method etc. if you press "`Tab`" it will jump to the next usage of it. Similar to VS.NET's `Ctrl + Shift + Down/up`

Is there anyway to do this in Resharper? Is there any plugin or a way for me to assign Tab to similar command in Resharper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ReSharper has this functionality, but only after you have either found or highlighted the usages of a variable/method/etc...

The keyboard shortcuts depend on whether you are using the Visual Studio or IDEA keyboard mappings (set in `ReSharper -> Options -> Visual Studio Integration -> Keybarod Shortcuts`).

To find the usages, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> (Visual Studio) or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> (IDEA).

To highlight usages, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> (Visual Studio) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> (IDEA).

Once you have done either of the above, you can move to the next usage using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>FPgDn</kbd> (Visual Studio) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> (IDEA).

[This ReSharper help page](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html) has a more complete set of shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks but this one takes 3 shortcuts and ~12 keypresses :) not that helpful really while coding. If you seen CodeRush Tab usage you can understand how it's used, unlike find usages it's like whatever you are over press Tab to "go to next usage". I went through the shortcut page before opening the question but couldn't find any shortcut that gets close to this feature.

Comment: @dr evil: Yes, it's not ideal keypress wise. From experience, you either love R# or love CodeRush - switching between them is always hard if you are used to the other.

Comment: Agreed, I love CodeRush. Only reason I'm switching to R# is C# background-compiling/analysis + formatting feature. CodeRush is lacking this and rest of the team doesn't love me if I don't format my C# code as they do :)

Comment: Two crucial features that I can't find in R#, this "Tab" thingy and awesome bookmarking model (drop marking stuff) of CodeRush

Comment: @dr evil: R# does have bookmarks, although I don't know how they compare to CodeRush - http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Bookmarks.html

Comment: I know R#'s bookmark support but CodeRush have a stack based bookmarking system with some auto bookmark support (drop marker before jump) etc. works quite different and effectively